# Is there a fix for Bootstrap 3 modals on Android 2.x?

Tags: android, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

On Android 2.x, I cannot get Bootstrap modals to work. They open properly, but then they will not scroll if they are larger than the screen. And you can't click on any of the buttons to close the dialog. Basically, it opens and displays properly, but is completely dead in the water in terms of interacting with the modal.

Bootstrap has no interest in fixing it as they don't support older Android versions. But, I thought there simply HAS to be a way to make it work, right? But apparently not.

I have tried the following hacks, and none of them work. They're all at least a year old, so perhaps they applied to Bootstrap 2.x, but they aren't working for Bootstrap 3.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8975#issuecomment-24804826

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9890#issuecomment-22915234

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5589#issuecomment-9745069

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3230#issuecomment-5629022

And so on...

Does anyone out there have a solution? Or do I have to use a different modal component? I'm required to support all versions of Android for this project, regretfully.

Comment: Be aware that on Android 2.x the in-app webview was subject to the whims of the ODM. Even though you had access to the open-source Android project that doesn't always reflect what was running on device.

Comment: I'm using Browserstack's emulator, which tells you which version of the browser it's running. I have to support the native browser that ships with the phone. Le sigh.

Comment: "I'm required to support all versions of Android for this project"  May `$DEITY` have mercy on your soul.

Comment: From your lips to `$DIETY's` ears. I recognize your username from the many github posts I've read, so you know my task is futile. I'm just going to use a more stylized version of the jquery dialog until said `$DIETY` has banished RAZRs and S2s from existence.